# JavaScript параметры Dom элемента

Tags: javascript, html

Видел видео как тип прописал какую то команду в js скрипте и ему выбило весь список параметров для этого объекта в браузере. Как это сделать самостоятельно для любого другого объекта? Вот у него выбило все параметры для тега div.

Comment: https://youtu.be/-2WiaSvOj78 время 42. 53

Comment: Ну, там отлично видно код. Видно, как в функцию передать объект. Переписывайте его себе и используйте на здоровье. В чём вопрос?

Comment: В общем это универсальное свойство? Подходит ко всем объектам? Просто он так сказал что "все это якобы только div" касается. Вот мне стало интересно может у других объектов есть что то еще

Comment: «Подходит ко всем объектам?» — За эти 12 минут уже могли бы сами переписать код и попробовать применить его к другим объектам :)

Comment: Спасибо за советы)

Comment: Открываете консоль,выбираете элемент и смотрите for(let i in $0){
 console.log(i)
}

Answer (score 2):

DOM-элемент в контексте JS представляет из себя объект, который, как мы знаем, можно перебирать:

```js
function print (e, name) {
  if (typeof e !== 'object') throw new Error('I need an object, call me an object');
  let props = [];
  
  for (let key in e) {
    props.push(`<strong>${key}</strong>: ${e[key]}`); // Тут свойства так же из прототипа
  }
  
  document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML += `<h3>${name}</h3><ul><li>${props.join('</li><li>')}</li></ul>`;
}
let tmp = {z: 42, q: "Hi"};

print (tmp, 'Tmp');
print (document.querySelector('div'), 'Div');
```

```html
<div></div>
<pre></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="out" >
    Просто блок
</div>
<!--Нажимаешь сочетание клавиш Ctrl + Shift + I и кликаешь на div, и снизу отобразится событие. Кликаешь на него и смотришь-->
<script type="text/javascript" >
    window.onload = function () {
        document.getElementById('out').onclick = function (event) {
            console.log(event);
        }
    }
</script>
```